# Inserting a Matrix to XML

Tags: c#, xml, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to insert data from Matrix to XML. How can I do that?

```
internal static XDocument createData(string[,] banciforxml)
{
    XDocument Bancile = new XDocument();
    Bancile.Add(new XElement("bancks", 
                             banciforxml.Select(x => new XElement("item", x))));
    return Bancile;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the XML to look like?

Comment: <banci>
   <bancks1>
     <item1>123</item1>
     <item2>123</item2>
     <item3>123</item3>
   </bancks>
   <bancks>
     <item1>123</item1>
     <item2>123</item2>
     <item3>123</item3>
   </bancks1>
</banci>

Comment: This XML is invalid. Is the element name `bancks1` or `bancks`?

Comment: i want to create XML dinamically 
i don't know if it possible,bot i think create a loop for extracting from the array[] [] and in that loop insert and create nodes in xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
public XDocument createData(string[,] banciforxml)
{
    XDocument Bancile = new XDocument();

    XElement root = new XElement("banci");

    Bancile.Add(root);

    //Go through the first dimension of the array
    for (int i = banciforxml.GetLowerBound(0); i <= banciforxml.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        var d1element = new XElement("bancks");

        root.Add(d1element);

        //Go though the second dimension of the array
        for (int j = banciforxml.GetLowerBound(1); j <= banciforxml.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        {
            var value = banciforxml[i, j];

            if(value == null)
                continue;

            var d2element = new XElement("item" + (j+1));

            d2element.Value = value;

            d1element.Add(d2element);
        }
    }

    return Bancile;
}
```

This code uses [`GetLowerBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`GetUpperBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to get the lower and upper indexes of each of the two dimensions of the array.

Comment: one moment i will send you the main code
and you will understand

Comment: @RomaBilibov, doesn't this code work for you? What issue are you facing?

Comment: d2element.Value = banciforxml[i, j];
it says that "Value cannot be null"

Comment: Upper I send the main code where i create the array

Comment: @RomaBilibov, I updated the code to handle `null` values. If it gets a `null` it would skip it.

Comment: This means that if the 2nd item is `null`, you would get `Item1`, `Item3`, `Item4`...

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb ht = new HtmlWeb();
        //XDocument Mydocument = Data.createData();
        //MessageBox.Show(Mydocument.ToString());
        //Data.SaveData("myfirst.xml");
        try
        {
            doc = ht.Load("http://www.curs.md/curs_valutar_banci");
        }

        catch 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Eroare la conectare cu sursa...");
            Close();
        }
        string[] result = new string[50];
        string[] banci = new string[] { "bnm", "eneg", "ecb", "exim", "fin", "mobi", "micb", "maib", "proc", "vb" };
        string[,] banciforxml=new string[10,15];
        for (int i = 0; i < banci.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr[@class='" + banci[i] + "']/td");
                for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
                {
                    result[x] = nodes[x].InnerText;
                    banciforxml[i,x]=result[x];

                    listBox1.Items.Add("Result "+i+":"+x+" -> "+banciforxml[i,x]);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                string value = banci[i];
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "bnm":
                        MessageBox.Show("Banca Nationala nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "eneg":
                        MessageBox.Show("Energbank nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "ecb":
                        MessageBox.Show("EuroCreditBank nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "exim":
                        MessageBox.Show("Eximbank nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "fin":
                        MessageBox.Show("FinComBank nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "mobi":
                        MessageBox.Show("Mobiasbanca nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "micb":
                        MessageBox.Show("Moldindconbank nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "maib":
                        MessageBox.Show("Moldova Agroindbank nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "proc":
                        MessageBox.Show("ProCredit Bank nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                    case "vb":
                        MessageBox.Show("Victoriabank nu functioneaza!!");
                        continue;
                }

            }

        }
        XDocument myDocument=Data.createData(banciforxml);//<-Here is the problem
        listBox1.Items.Add(myDocument);
```

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34843962/edit) your question instead of posting an answer.